# Grouping dataframe by class column and time and then sum another column per class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a date column, a class column and a q_count column.

```
Date                       Class   q_count
2019-08-08 12:22:10+00:00  C1       21
2019-08-22 10:31:17+00:00  C1        5
2019-08-22 11:01:15+00:00  C1        7 
2019-08-24 12:02:32+00:00  C1        1
2019-08-30 06:15:06+00:00  C2       15 
2019-08-31 05:33:41+00:00  C1        2
2019-08-31 11:33:31+00:00  C1       10
2019-08-31 15:23:63+00:00  C1        2
2019-08-31 15:33:47+00:00  C1        6
2019-08-31 18:33:15+00:00  C1        2
...
```

I want to create a time series with a certain time bin and number of class occurrences in that bin and number of total q_counts per class in each bin. I have used the following to group the dataframe by class in weekly time bins:

```
df =df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'), 'class']).size().unstack('class')
df = df.melt(id_vars=["date"], var_name="class", value_name="class_counts")
```

```
Date                       Class   class_counts 
2019-08-11 00:00:00+00:00  C1      1
2019-08-25 00:00:00+00:00  C1      3
2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00  C1      5
2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00  C2      1
2016-08-28 00:00:00+00:00  C1      1
2016-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  C2      3
...
```

The time series looks fine but I need to have also a column q_counts_total so that the output would look like this:

```
Date                       Class   class_counts  q_counts_total
2019-08-11 00:00:00+00:00  C1      1             21
2019-08-25 00:00:00+00:00  C1      3             13
2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00  C1      5             22 
2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00  C2      1             15
2016-08-28 00:00:00+00:00  C1      1              9
2016-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  C2      3             21
...
```

where q_counts_total are the q_counts in each class summed in each time bin. I cannot figure out a way to approach the problem, since I am able to sum the q_counts per class with `df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'), 'q_counts', 'class']).size().unstack('class')` but in this way it sums all q_counts per class and I lose the time bin information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use named agg with groupby:

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Date'),'Class'])
   .agg(Class_counts=('Class','size'),
        q_counts_total=('q_count','sum'))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or usual `agg` on the `q_count` column and rename:

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Date'),'Class'])
   ['q_count'].agg(['size','sum'])
   .rename(columns={'size':'Class_counts','sum':'q_counts_total'})
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
                       Date Class  Class_counts  q_counts_total
0 2019-08-11 00:00:00+00:00    C1             1              21
1 2019-08-25 00:00:00+00:00    C1             3              13
2 2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00    C1             5              22
3 2019-09-01 00:00:00+00:00    C2             1              15
```

Comment: was about to post the same ^_^ faster guy wins!